# Unwrap array inside another array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am getting a string separated from commas and I am trying to split them into an array, which works. The only problem is that there is an outer array wrapping the array I want to use. So I don't want to use the `$excludes[0]` when passing the array to a function. Does anyone know a function I can use to unwrap the array inside `$excludes[0]`

```
$excludes = [];
 
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[0] => company_logo,
[1] => social_links,
[2] => rss_link,
[3] => telephone ) )
```

My expected results would be the below.

```
 
Array ( 
 [0] => company_logo,
 [1] => social_links,
 [2] => rss_link,
 [3] => telephone 
)
```

Comment: `$excludes = $excludes[0];` ...?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple do :

1st Option:

> print_r(array_shift($excludes));

2nd Option:

> ```
> $new_array = $excludes[0];
> print_r($new_array);
> ```

Hope this will work

Comment: I think I needed option 1, I was already covered with option two. Thank you, it works, I just need to read the function documentation.

Comment: @LehlohonoloMotsoeneng If my answer will help you then please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
 $excludes = Array ( 0 => Array ( 
                    0 => 'company_logo',
                    1 => 'social_links',
                    2 => 'rss_link',
                    3 => 'telephone' ) ) ;

            
                    $excludes=$excludes[0];
                    print_r($excludes);die();
```

Comment: This is my current solution, I however felt like it was a hack, so was hoping there's maybe a built in function to handle that. But thank you!